# is it possible to copy a file handle to another variable?

Tags: perl

I have a very straitforward question i couldn't find an answer for it.

Say we have a section of code that performs a common task (e.g., a sub), and the output of that code should be directed to a specific file handle based on some criteria.

Is it possible to copy the target file handle to a local variable? if yes how?

e.g.,

```
my $key;
my $tempFh;
my $targetFh1 = open (...);
my $targetFh2 = open (...);

if ($key eq "1")
{
   $tempFh = $targetFh1;
}
else
{
   $tempFh = $targetFh2;
}

#perform the common activity
print $tempFh "common activity\n";
```

Comment: If you were to try, you'll be in know already.

Comment: @mpapec - what makes you think i haven't tried/explored the web/StackOverflow and others?... the above code was always failing in my case.

Comment: Then your question title is wrong, it should read `How to open a file and use file handle` which is covered in [perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The only issue is the syntax of `open`.

```
my $targetFh1 = open (...);
my $targetFh2 = open (...);
```

should be

```
open(my $targetFh1, ...) or die $!;
open(my $targetFh2, ...) or die $!;
```

---

The rest is fine.

```
my $fh;
if ($key eq '1') {
   $fh = $targetFh1;
} else {
   $fh = $targetFh2;
}

print $fh "common activity\n";
```

(The word `temp` is completely meaningless, so I removed it.)

Another syntax you could use is

```
my $fh = $key eq '1' ? $targetFh1 : $targetFh2;
print $fh "common activity\n";
```

Or even

```
print { $key eq '1' ? $targetFh1 : $targetFh2 } "common activity\n";
```

---

But unless the `print` is in a loop and `$key` can change from loop pass to loop pass, there's no reason to open both files like that. You could simply use

```
my $fh;
if ($key eq '1') {
   open($fh, ...) or die $!;
} else {
   open($fh, ...) or die $!;
}

print $fh "common activity\n";
```

Comment: I would note it's more efficient to select a file and then open it rather than open two files, select one filehandle and throw the other filehandle away.

Comment: Throwing a file handle away isn't useful, but sometimes you want to do alternating output streams or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use 3 arg open with a lexical filehandle:

```
open ( my $output_fh, ">", $output_filename ) or die $!;
```

Assign the filehandle:

```
my $temp_fh_ref = $output_fh;
print {$temp_fh_ref} "Some text";
```

Works exactly like you'd expect. (Just bear in mind that if you close one, you'll close both)

Comment: Not my down-vote, but why the `{}` in the `print` line?

Comment: Style. `print {$temp_fh_ref}, "Some text";` generates compile time warnings, where `print $other_temp_fh,"More text\n";` is valid - it just doesn't 'work'. Also makes clear that it's a filehandle without having to go looking back through the code to figure out.